# Convert Tektronix's RIBinary data in TCL

Tags: binary, type-conversion, tcl

I am pulling data from a Tektronix oscilloscope in Tektronix' RIBinary format using a TCL script, and then within the script I need to convert that to a decimal value.

I have done very little with binary conversions in the first place, but to add to my frustration the documentation on this binary format is also very vague in my opinion. Anyway, here's my current code:

```
proc ::Scope::CaptureWaveform {VisaAlias Channel} {
    # Apply scope settings
    ::VISA::Write $VisaAlias "*WAI"
    ::VISA::Write $VisaAlias "DATa:STARt 1"
    ::VISA::Write $VisaAlias "DATa:STOP 4000"
    ::VISA::Write $VisaAlias "DATa:ENCdg RIBinary"
    ::VISA::Write $VisaAlias "DATa:SOUrce $Channel"

    # Download waveform
    set RIBinaryWaveform [::VISA::Query $VisaAlias "CURVe?"]

    # Parse out leading label from scope output
    set RIBinaryWaveform [string range $RIBinaryWaveform 11 end]

    # Convert binary data to a binary string usable by TCL
    binary scan $RIBinaryWaveform "I*" TCLBinaryWaveform
    set TCLBinaryWaveform

    # Convert binary data to list
}
```

Now, this code pulls the following data from the machine:

-1064723993 -486674282 50109321 -6337556 70678 8459972 143470359 1046714383 1082560884 1042711231 1074910212 1057300801 1061457453 1079313832 1066305613 1059935120 1068139252 1066053580 1065228329 1062213553

And this is what the machine pulls when I just take regular ASCII data (i.e. what the above data should look like after the conversion):

-1064723968 -486674272 50109320 -6337556 70678 8459972 143470352 1046714368 1082560896 1042711232 1074910208 1057300800 1061457472 1079313792 1066305600 1059935104 1068139264 1066053568 1065228352 1062213568

Finally, here is a reference to the RIBinary specification from Tektronix since I don't think it is a standard data type:

http://www.tek.com/support/faqs/how-binary-data-represented-tektronix-oscilloscopes

I've been looking for a while now on the Tektronix website for more information on converting the data and the above URL is all I've been able to find, but I'll comment or edit this post if I find any more information that might be useful.

*Updates*

- Answers don't necessarily have to be in TCL. If anyone can help me logically work through this on a high level I can hash out the TCL details (this I think would be more helpful to others as well)
- The reason I need to transfer the data in binary and then convert it afterwards is for the purpose of optimization. Due to this I can't have the device perform the conversion before the transfer as it will slow down the process.
- I updated my code some and now my results are maddeningly close to the actual results. I assume it may have something to do with the commas that are in the data originally.
- Below are now examples of the raw data sent from the device without any of my parsing.
- On suggestion from @kostix, I made a second script with code he gave me that I modified to fit my data set. It can be seen below, however the result are exactly the same as my above code.

`ASCIi`:

> :CURVE -1064723968,-486674272,50109320,-6337556,70678,8459972,143470352,1046714368,1082560896,1042711232,1074910208,1057300800,1061457472,1079313792,1066305600,1059935104,1068139264,1066053568,1065228352,1062213568

RIBinary:

:CURVE #280ÀçâýðüÿKì

Note on RIBinary - ":CURVE #280" is all part of the header that I need to parse out, but the #280 part of it can vary depending on the data I'm collecting. Here's some more info from Tektronix on what the #280 means:

> block is the waveform data in binary format. The waveform is formatted
>   as: # where  is the number of y bytes. For
>   example, if  = 500, then  = 3.  is the number of bytes to
>   transfer including checksum.

So, for my current data set x = 2 and yyy = 80. I am just really unfamiliar with converting binary data, so I'm not sure what to do programmatically to deal with the block format.

On suggestion from @kostix I made a second script with code he gave me that I modified to fit my data set:

```
set RIBinaryWaveform [::VISA::Query ${VisaAlias} "CURVe?"]

binary scan $RIBinaryWaveform a8a curv nbytes

encoding convertfrom ascii ${curv}

scan $nbytes %u n

set n

set headerlen [expr {$n + 9}]

binary scan $RIBinaryWaveform @9a$n nbytes

scan $nbytes %u n

set n

set numints [expr {$n / 4}]

binary scan $RIBinaryWaveform @${headerlen}I${numints} data

set data
```

The output of this code is the same as the code I provided above.

Comment: If `::VISA::Query` returns a comma-terminated header followed by binary data, don't use `split` because there may be commas in the data. Also, `split` will return **a list** with [escape characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14227782/stray-characters-coming-after-splitting-the-list-in-tcl) intertwined with the data, which `binary scan` will interpret as part of the data since it expects **a string**. Remove the header by finding the first `,` instead, or do use `split` but then you have to `join` it together to a string again after removing the first element (the header).

Comment: @potrzebie the data it returns is only separated by spaces, it actually appears just as I depicted above, only having a header separated by a space in front of it. In the case of the binary data it returns the header, still in ASCII, a space and then 1 binary string containing all the data. So, the parsing works exactly the same either way.

Comment: Text characters are stored in bytes too. If there are bytes in the binary data with the value 44 (the ASCII value for `,`), your `split` will replace them with `} {` or something like that, i.e. three bytes with the values 123, 32 and 125. Also: if the header is terminated with space, why the comma?

Comment: @potrzebie you were correct, the data is comma separated when it comes out of the scope, I had just been parsing it for so long I had forgotten. I'll update my question to reflect this.

Comment: @potrzebie I updated the code in my question and now my results are maddeningly close to what they should be, I assume it may have something to do with the commas that are in the data originally, but could you take a look and see if anything jumps out at you as to why the results would be just a few digits off of the actual numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation you link to, RIBinary is signed big-endian. Thus, you convert the binary data to integers with `binary scan $data "I*" someVar` (`I*` means “as many big-endian 4-byte integers as you can”). You use the same conversion with RPBinary (if you've got that) but you then need to chop each value to the positive 32-bit integer range by doing `& 0xFFFFFFFF` (assuming at least Tcl 8.5). For FPBinary, use `R*` (requires 8.5). SRIBinary, SRPBinary and SFPBinary are the little-endian versions, for which you use lower-case format characters.

Getting conversions correct can take some experimentation.

Comment: Okay so I added this to my code: binary scan $TCLBinaryWaveform "I*" Waveform; set Waveform and it returned far too much data, somewhere in the area of 50+ integers all above 80,000,000. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Chrono, well, the result of your `binary scan ... b*` represents 672 bits which is equivalent to 21 32-bit integers, not 50+. I don't really know what to draw from it, just some simple math. May it be that you somehow misinterpret the header which precedes the binary data? In fact I don't like the straight jump from list operations to `binary scan` in your code: usually when working with on-the-wire binary formats you use *only* binary scanning *first,* and more high-level operations only after "unpacking" the data. Feel free to elaborate on the format of the returned data.

Comment: @Chrono, as to the value of these integers -- it's even harder to say anything: you ought to know what values appear to be sensible for the kind of data your device is supposed to return. If you think the result of the decoding is *not* sensible this is a clear hint you're decoding it wrong for now. But asking us if your data looks okay is rather futile ;-)

Comment: @kostix I updated the code in my question and now my results are maddeningly close to what they should be, I assume it may have something to do with the commas that are in the data originally, but could you take a look and see if anything jumps out at you as to why the results would be just a few digits off of the actual numbers?

Comment: @Chrono The other thing I don't know about is how much framing data there should be. Alas, you're going to have to very carefully read the documentation (and *beware*! Hardware hackers do dreadful things to data to try to shave off another few transistors…)

Comment: @Chrono, I've updated my answer with a step-by-step instruction of how to play with the binary data like yours. Hope it helps.

Comment: This answer originally solved my problem therefore I am accepting it, the ASCII values were actually what were wrong from the beginning, @donal take a look at the answer I posted if you are interested in an explaination. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

I have no experience with this stuff but like googleing. Here are my findings.

[This document](http://www.ni.com/pdf/manuals/370423a.pdf), in the section titled "Formatted I/O Operations" tells that the `viQueryf()` standard C API function combines `viPrintf()` (writing to a device) with `viScanf()` (reading from a device), and examples include calls like `viQueryf (io, ":CURV?\n", "%#b", &totalPoints, rdBuffer);` (see the section «IEEE-488.2 Binary Data—"%b"»), where the third argument to the function specifies the desired format.

The `VISA::Query` procedure from your Tcl library pretty much resembles that `viQueryf()` in my eyes, so I'd expect it to accept the third (optional) argument which specifies the format *you* want the data to be in.

If there's nothing like it, let's look at your ASCII data. Your FAQ entry and the document I found both specify that the opaque data might come in the form of a series of integers of different size and endianness. The "RIBinary" format states it should be big-endian signed integers.

The `binary scan` Tcl command is able to scan 16-bit and 32-bit big-endian integers from a byte stream — use the `S*` and `I*` formats, correspondingly.

Your ASCII data clearly looks like 32-bit integers, so I'd try scanning using `I*`.

Also see [this doc](http://www.ni.com/white-paper/4727/en) — it appears to have much in common with the PDF guide I linked above, but might be handy anyway.

TL;DR

- Try studying your API to find a way to explicitly tell the device the data format you want. This might produce a more robust solution in the case the device might be somehow reconfigured externally to change its default data format effectively pulling the rug under the feet of your code which relies on certain (guessed) default.
- Try interpreting the data as outlined above and see if the interpretation looks sensible.

P.S.
This might mean nothing at all, but I failed to find any example which has "e" between the "CURV" and the "?" in the calls to `viQueryf()`.

*Update* (2013-01-17, in light of the new discoveries about the data format): to `binary scan` the data of varying types, you might employ two techniques:

- `binary scan` accepts as many specifiers in a row, you like; they're are processed from left to right as `binary scan` reads the supplied data.
- You can do multiple runs of `binary scan`ning over a chunk of your binary data either by cutting pieces of this chunk (string manipulation Tcl commands understand they're operating on a byte array and behave accordingly) or use the `@offset` term in the `binary scan` format string to make it start scanning from the specified offset.

Another technique worth employing here is that you'd better first train yourself on a toy example. This is best done in an interactive Tcl shell — [`tkcon`](http://tkcon.sf.net) is a best bet but plain `tclsh` is also OK, especially if called via `rlwrap` (POSIX systems only).

For instance, you could create a fake data for yourself like this:

```
% set b [encoding convertto ascii ":CURVE #224"]
:CURVE #224
% append b [binary format S* [list 0 1 2 -3 4 -5 6 7 -8 9 10 -11]]
:CURVE #224............
```

Here we first created a byte array containing the header and then created another byte array containing twelve 16-bit integers packed MSB first, and then appended it to the first array essentially creating a data block our device is supposed to return (well, there's less integers than the device returns). [`encoding convertto`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/encoding.htm) takes the name of a character encoding and a string and produces a binary array of that string converted to the specified encoding. `binary format` is told to consume a list of arbitrary size (`*` in the format list) and interpret it as a list of 16-bit integers to be packed in the big-endian format — the `S` format character.

Now we can scan it back like this:

```
% binary scan $b a8a curv nbytes
2
% encoding convertfrom ascii $curv
:CURVE #
% scan $nbytes %u n
1
% set n
2
% set headerlen [expr {$n + 9}]
11
% binary scan $b @9a$n nbytes
1
% scan $nbytes %u n
1
% set n
24
% set numints [expr {$n / 2}]
12
% binary scan $b @${headerlen}S${numints} data
1
% set data
0 1 2 -3 4 -5 6 7 -8 9 10 -11
```

Here we proceeded like this:

1. Interpret the header:

   1. Read the first eight bytes of the data as ASCII characters (`a8`) — this should read our `:CURVE #` prefix. We convert the header prefix from the packed ASCII form to the Tcl's internal string encoding using `encoding convertfrom`.
   2. Read the next byte (`a`) which is then interpreted as the length, in bytes, of the next field, using the [`scan`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/scan.htm) command.

      We then calculate the length of the header read so far to use it later. This values is saved to the "headerlen" variable. The length of the header amounts to the 9 fixed bytes plus variable-number of bytes (2 in our case) specifying the length of the following data.
   3. Read the next field which will be interpreted as the "number of data bytes" value.

      To do this, we offset the scanner by 9 (the length of ":CURVE #2") and read so many ASCII bytes as obtained on the previous step, so we use `@9a$n` for the format: `$n` is just obtaining the value of a variable named "n", and it will be 2 in our case. Then we `scan` the obtained value and finally get the number of the following raw data.

      Since we will read 16-bit integers, not bytes, we divide this number by 2 and store the result to the "numints" variable.
2. Read the data. To do this, we have to offset the scanner by the length of the header. We use `@${headerlen}S${numints}` for the format string. Tcl expands those `${varname}` before passing the string to the `binary scan` so the actual string in our case will be `@11S12` which means "offset by 11 bytes then scan 12 16-bit big-endian integers".

   `binary scan` puts a list of integers to the variable which name is passed, so no additional decoding of those integers is needed.

Note that in the real program you should probably do certain sanity checks:
* After the first step check that the static part of the header is really ":CURVE #".
* Check the return value of `binary scan` and `scan` after each invocation and check it equals to the number of variables passed to the command (which means the command was able to parse the data).

One more insight. The manual you cited says:

> is the number of bytes to transfer including checksum.

so it's quite possible that not all of those data bytes represent measures, but some of them represent the checksum.  I don't know what format (and hence length) and algorithm and position of this checksum is.  But if the data does indeed include a checksum, you can't interpret it all using `S*`.  Instead, you will probably take another approach:

1. Extract the measurement data using `string range` and save it to a variable.
2. `binary scan` the checksum field.
3. Calculate the checksum on the data obtained on the first step, verify it.
4. Use `binary scan` on the extracted data to get back your measurements.

Checksumming procedures are available in [`tcllib`](http://tcllib.sf.net).

Comment: I appreciate the answer and I realize I should have specified that the reason I need to transfer the data in binary and then convert it afterward is for the purpose of optimization. Due to this I can't have the device perform the conversion before the transfer as it will slow down the process. I'll add this as an update to my question. I'm about to respond to @donalfellows and that should address the rest of your post.

Comment: Okay, I modified the code that you suggested to match my data set: binary scan $RIBinaryWaveform a8a curv nbytes; encoding convertfrom ascii ${curv}; scan $nbytes %u n; set n; set headerlen [expr {$n + 9}]; binary scan $RIBinaryWaveform @9a$n nbytes; scan $nbytes %u n; set n; set numints [expr {$n / 4}]; binary scan $RIBinaryWaveform @${headerlen}I${numints} data; set dat; However, the results are exact same as I got previously. Those results being the ones that are off by the last couple digits.

Comment: (continuing previous comment) I assume the skewed results have to be due to the checksum, but the only mention I can find of the checksum in any Tektronix documentation is that one line: "number of bytes to transfer including checksum". Also what is interesting is the amount of data I am getting back. It always has exactly enough bytes to hold the header and an even number of 32-bit integers, so technically there shouldn't be any room for a checksum in the data. Is there anyway to test this further without documentation on the checksum or the algorithm that is generating the data?

Comment: @Chrono, sorry but I don't know what to suggest now... Your ASCII representation example contains 20 integers; how many 32-bit integers fit in the amount of binary data you're getting?

Comment: Exactly 20 32-bit integers unfortunately, 640 bits. Essentially there shouldn't be room for a checksum and I'm beginning to think that line is just a mistake in the documentation on their part since it is the one and only mention of a checksum.

Comment: @Chrono, well unless one of those integers is the checksum. You could also not trust the description of that RIBinary format and try interpreting your integers as little-endian. As I have no idea what kind of data your oscilloscope is *supposed* to return, I'm unable to do any guesses. Might be your ASCII representation is wrong after all and the device is sending 16-bit integers. Try any variations until the decoded data looks sensible.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, I'm working with one of Tektronix's software engineers on the issue now, we are starting to think that ASCIi data is incorrect and the binary data is the correct results. This is from how the software on the scope is converting the binary data to ASCIi before it transmits it. I'll post a full solution in an answer when we get it completely resolved.

Comment: Indeed there is no checksum, mention of it was left over from previous printings of the programmer's manual from previous models of the unit. I posted an answer explaining the solution. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

```
# Download waveform
set RIBinaryWaveform [::VISA::Query ${VisaAlias} "CURVe?"]

# Extract block format data
set ResultCount [expr [string range ${RIBinaryWaveform} 2 [expr [string index${RIBinaryWaveform} 1] + 1]] / 4]

# Parse out leading label from Tektronics block format
set RIBinaryWaveform [string range ${RIBinaryWaveform} [expr [string index ${RIBinaryWaveform} 1] + 2] end]

# Convert binary data to integer values
binary scan ${RIBinaryWaveform} "I${ResultCount}" Waveform
set Waveform
```

Okay, the code above does the magic trick. This is very similar to all the things discussed on this page, but I figured I needed to clear up the confusion about the numbers from the binary conversion being different from the numbers received in ASCII.

After troubleshooting with a Tektronix application specialist we discovered that the data I had been receiving after the binary conversion (the numbers that were off by a few digits) were actually the true values captured by the scope.

The reason the *ASCII values are wrong* is a result of the binary-to-ASCII conversion done by the instrument and then the incorrect values are then passed by the scope to TCL.

So, we had it right a few days ago. The instrument was just throwing me for a loop.